# помогите понять как работает данный код с шифром виженера?

Tags: c++

нашел код шифрующий слово с помощью "шифр виженера" но никак не могу понять как работает программа может кто ни будь объяснить словами как он работает?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string text;
    std::string key;
    std::string result;
    cin >> text;
    cin >> key;
    for(int i = key.size(), j = 0; i < text.size(); i++){
        key += key[j];
        j++;
    }

    

    for(int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++){
        int ascii = int(text[i]) + int(key[i]) % 97;
        ascii -= (ascii > 122) ? 26 : 0 ;
        result += char(ascii);
    }

    std::cout << result;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kueULgDkA5k

Comment: я знаю что такое шифр вижнера но мне нужно обьеснение как работает именно этот код

Comment: Вы не сказали, что именно вам не понятно! Объяснять так неэффективно, был бы, хоть, вопрос полезен для сообщества, так нет. Кодов миллиард же встречается в интернете, вам каждый объяснять чуть что? Попробуйте, пожалуйста, реализовать шифр сами! Используйте этот код как ориентир, старайтесь как можно меньше в него подглядывать. Вам никто так не объяснит, как вы сами себе объясните в результате, не просите и не вынуждайте эту работу никого проделывать за вас:)

Answer (score 2):

1. Обращение к строке с индексатором (например `text[i]` в Вашем коде) - это обращение к одному символу строки text.
2. Приведение одного символа к типу `int` - получение его номера в кодовой таблице ASCII
3. Рассмотрим сам цикл шифрования

```
for(int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++)
{
    int ascii = int(text[i]) + int(key[i]) % 97;
    ascii -= (ascii > 122) ? 26 : 0 ;
    result += char(ascii);
}
```

Тут мы идем по строке посимвольно, вычисляем сумму символа строки и ключа. Берем от полученного результата деление по модулю 97. Нужно это затем, чтобы не выйти за пределы алфавита, т.е. если в результате суммы у Вас получилось 99, вместо этого вы перейдете на символ номер 2 в алфавите ASCII, а не выйдете за границы этого алфавита.

`ascii -= (ascii > 122) ? 26 : 0 ;`
Эта строка - по сути условный оператор. Если ваш полученный символ больше 122 (хотя по сути он не может получиться больше 97 из-за кода выше), то отнять от символа 26, т.е. сместиться на 26 символов влево по алфавиту. Иначе отнять 0, т.е. оставить символ как есть.

Последняя строка в цикле - просто присоединение этого символа к результирующей строке.

UPD: Понятия не имею, что из себя представляет шифр Виженера, однако, т.к. у вас в цикле не выполняется никогда условие `ascii > 122`, вы получаете посути просто чуть более сложный шифр Цезаря, где вместо единого сдвига на весь текст имеется ключ для сдвига.

Answer (score 0):

Все более-менее просто

Считывается шифруемый текст

```
cin >> text;
```

Считывается ключ

```
cin >> key;
```

Ключ повторяется многократно, пока длина не сравняется с длиной текста - типа, для текста длиной 10 символов ключ `abc` превращается в `abcabcabca`

```
for(int i = key.size(), j = 0; i < text.size(); i++){
    key += key[j];
    j++;
}
```

Каждый символ текста

```
for(int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++){
```

шифруется с помощью соответствующего символа ключа

```
    int ascii = int(text[i]) + int(key[i]) % 97;
```

если символ вылетает за пределы алфавита, его бессмысленно пытаются вернуть назад :)

```
    ascii -= (ascii > 122) ? 26 : 0 ;
```

и дописывают к результату

```
    result += char(ascii);
}
```

Примерно так... Шифр Виженера - достаточно частый гость здесь, на ruSO, и вам достаточно было выполнить поиск [здесь же](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0). Посмотрите вопросы/ответы по указанной ссылке.